# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to int

Tags: java, eclipse, session, integer, int

Thank you for the replies so far.

The exception stack trace is below. As for the java compiler being used, it is whatever is running in Websphere Application Server v6.1 within this version of the tool. And adding _b resolved the error on some of the lines but not all of them. I'm not sure that that would be the correct logic to use here. But I won't know that until I actually get it running again. set.Attribute("rowcount",rowcount); also has the first error before and after changing it to set.Attribute("rowcount",rowcount_b);  So for this variable your solution had no effect. Strange. The whole problem is just strange to me.

```
Integer rowcount_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("rowcount");  
if (rowcount_b == null) {
    session.setAttribute("rowcount",rowcount_b);
}
// else {
//   rowcount = rowcount_b;
// }
```

I had to do the commenting out of these three lines with all of the if statements of this flavor when attempting to apply your suggestion. But it did not matter with rowcount.

```
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:444)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:295)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
```

I am using ...

IBM Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software

Version: 7.5.5.5 iFix1
   Build ID: RADO7555iFix1-I20120913_1613

The errors I receive are:

The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type HttpSession is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to int

They occur on these lines:

```
 session.setAttribute("rowsremaining",rowsremaining);
 rowsremaining = rowsremaining_b;
 session.setAttribute("pos",pos);
 pos = pos_b;
```

Of the following code (snippet):

```
if (session.getAttribute("searchresults") != null) {   // Tests to make sure the session information was created and passed back from the servlet.
                                                        // If yes, press on, otherwise, display error msg

      ArrayList resultsArray = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("searchresults");

      if (resultsArray.size()>0) {
         int totaldata = resultsArray.size();  
         int totalrows = totaldata / 10;

         int remainingdata = resultsArray.size(); 
         int rowsremaining = remainingdata/10; 

     // The starting position within the list of returned information

        int pos = 0; 

     // The starting row count - decremented for each row displayed

        int rowcount = 10;  

     // Get the previously stored values of rowsremaining and pos, 
     //if this is the same search, otherwise, they will be as defined above

        Integer rowsremaining_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("rowsremaining");  
        if (rowsremaining_b == null) {
           session.setAttribute("rowsremaining",rowsremaining);
        }
        else {
          rowsremaining = rowsremaining_b;
        }

        Integer pos_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("pos");  
        if (pos_b == null) {
           session.setAttribute("pos",pos);
        }
        else {
          pos = pos_b;
        }
```

This was working before, ie., no runtime errors, so I'm not sure what I messed with just
   yet to suddenly gain these errors upon clicking "Run on Server1". After noticing the errors

I set

`Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Error/Warnings --> Potential Programming Problems --> Boxing and Unboxing conversions`

from its default value of Ignore to Error so that I could see the above lines which were the ones in error. Because traveling to the java file via

`Program Files --> IBM --> SDP --> runtimes --> base_v61 --> profiles --> was61profile1 --> temp --> node ...`

all the way to the war directory was a bit of a pain :-) (after opening with an editor that shows me the line numbers that were mentioned).

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace. Autoboxing or Inboxing should do it for you.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I've seen this both when the JDK/JRE weren't set (or set incorrectly to a version that didn't support boxing), and when there were class loader issues - It's more likely the former though.

Comment: Ah....from the Server startup messages...Java version = 1.5.0, Java Compiler = j9jit23, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

Comment: Goibniu, how can I determine either? Right now all errors are gone but the logic is as I feared, all screwy, I keep seeing the same 10 rows of information, despite clicking the next 10 button. Because now I have this  Integer rowsremaining_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("rowsremaining");  
session.setAttribute("rowsremaining",rowsremaining_b); for pos and for rowcount as well. Code worked in Websphere 7 Redhat Linux env  with an Oracle DB. Now its Websphere 6.1 with Windows 7 and an MS Access DB. I still have my good bkup of working app, but its moving to this new environment giving grief.

Comment: I don't feel like I should have to change the logic too much. The conn and query statements...oh yes, those had to be changed to return results (Upper becoming ucase, etc.), but the code that processes the returned results, I don't understand why I should have to make changes to that. That should still work. Class Loader issues?

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 lines resolved my problem.

```
  pos_b = new Integer(pos);
  rowcount_b = new Integer(rowcount);
  rowsremaining_b = new Integer(rowsremaining);
```

So that after I stored them

```
  session.setAttribute("pos",pos_b);
  session.setAttribute("rowsremaining",rowsremaining_b);   
  session.setAttribute("rowcount",rowcount_b);
```

I could retrieve them

```
  Integer rowsremaining_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("rowsremaining");  
    if (rowsremaining_b == null) {
       session.setAttribute("rowsremaining",rowsremaining);
    }
    else {
      rowsremaining = rowsremaining_b;
    }

    Integer pos_b = (Integer) session.getAttribute("pos");  
    if (pos_b == null) {
       session.setAttribute("pos",pos);
    }
    else {
      pos = pos_b;
    }
```